# How withCredentials works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, request, cookie-httponly

I want to send httpOnly cookies in request's header. I found that I can use withCredentials: true but I can't found information (with example) how it works. How does request know which cookie it must send. If I created instance (axios.create()) and i made cookie after login it will work?

Comment: cookies have a domain (and other things) ... basically (it's a little more complex) any cookie for domain x.y.z will be sent **only** to x.y.z - whether they are httpOnly or not is irrelevant

Comment: So I created cookie in PHP and it will be usingh automatically?

Comment: yes that's the theory